# MDaemon Emails - spam issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vps, spam, mdaemon

last days i installed MDAEMON 10 in windows server 2008-r2.(in my VPS -> have remote access)
it seems every thing was ok, but at the begining of sending  emails i had `Delivery Email Error`
for solving that issue i went to the site below :
http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso
and add my ip address for removing from Policy Block List.
so at now every thing is ok for **recieveing emails** and **sending emails to gmail accounts**.
but my problem is about **sending emails to yahoo accounts**.
one of those emails at recipient is like this :

```
Body Text goes here...

and this is advertisement :  
    TODAY(Beta)
    Kris Humphries booed in NBA return
    Kim Kardashian's ex sparks a strong reaction the moment he steps on the court.
    Powered by Yahoo! • Privacy Policy
```

it seems i am still in their black list and there is advertisement in sent emails.
why am i in their black list and how can i fix that and remove advertisement ?

**Edit After Comment :**

```
how you configured MDaemon
```

I did n't change any thing in MDaemon and every thing is default.(in another server i act like this and every thing was ok about sending and recieving mails)

```
what are the exact error messages?
```

As i said Delivery Error wanished after adding my ip to spamhaus.
but there is a problem for sending mails to yahoo.
in recipient side (MDaemon is sender , yahoo mail is recipient) that mail has advertisement inside and goes to spam(bulk) list.

```
how you came to the idea to check (just) Spamhaus' RLBs
```

In a forum somebody told me to check that.(i have no idea about that)(is there another place for checking blacklist?)

```
how the advertisement ended on the e-mail when you have problems sending mails to Yahoo`
```

What do you mean?

```
How did you came to the conclusion that you are on Yahoos Blacklist?
```

Because those mails (sent by MDAEMON) go to bulk folder without any reason.

```
Can you deliver mails to Yahoo addresses?
```

Yes, i can deliver them.but they go to bulk(spam) folder.

```
Are you annoyed by the added advertisements or anything else?
```

By the added advertisements and spam issue.

Comment: downvoter - just give me a comment!

Comment: Your question doesn't make all that much sense and misses about all relevant information, like how you configured MDaemon, what the exact error messages are, how you came to the idea to check (just) Spamhaus' RLBs, how the advertisement ended on the e-mail when you have problems sending mails to Yahoo, how you came to the conclusion that you are on Yahoos Blacklist etc.etc.  In the end, I am not sure at all what your problem is. Can't you deliver mails to Yahoo addresses, are you annoyed by the added advertisements or anything else.

Comment: @SvenW, plz see my Q again!

Comment: You transformed your "question" to a bunch of more questions without giving any relevant information. So you made up a discussion which is not accepted by the [FAQ].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting mail right is complicated, installing an SMTP server is just  the first (or last) step to get everything working.

I have no idea why your mails might end up tagged as spam by Yahoo, but to get reliable E-Mail service you have to consider at least the following issues:

- No dial-up IP address. Many providers block these outright, for good reasons.
- No low-reputation IP addresses from some cheap and/or shady providers. Some consider them as bad as dial-up addresses, and you can't do a lot about it except switching providers.
- No open relay. This means nobody should be allowed to use your mail server as relay to other domains without authentication.
- Correctly configured DNS entries with both forward and reverse addresses and MX records.
- Don't send spam. Be strict about it.
- Optional, but ever more useful are correct [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DKIM) and/or [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records.
- Spamhaus is only one RBL. Check others with a meta search tool like [MXToolBox.com](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx).

The advertisement was likely included automatically by Yahoo as part as their business model: You get free mail and have to accept they add advertisements to your incoming and outgoing mail.